# Как написать регулярку, которая выберет из текста только некоторые цифры

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Ниже даны три строки текста, из этого текста нужно выбрать только те цифры, которые идут после слова file и собрать их в массив.

```
Текст который будет записан в файл с именем file1.txt (level-3.js)
Текст который будет записан в файл с именем file12.txt (level-3.js)
Текст который будет записан в файл с именем file123.txt (level-3.js)
```

Больше часа уже бьюсь, пробовал генераторы регулярок, но увы ничего не помогает.
Максимум что я смог это написать вот это:

```
const allData = (data1 + data2 + data3)
          .replace(/[^[0-9]/g, ' ')
          .split(' ')
          .filter((item) => item !== '');

//В data1, data2, data3 соответственно те 3 строки, выше.
```

Но проблема в том, что эта регулярка захватывает цифру 3, идущую за level-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать позитивную ретроспективную (lookbehind) проверку и опережающую (lookahead) проверку.

- позитивная ретроспективная проверка:

`(?<=expr1)expr2` - ищет совпадение с expr2 при условии, что перед ним находится expr1.

- опережающая проверка:

`expr1(?=expr2)` - ищет совпадение с expr1 при условии, что после него следует expr2

```js
const data1 = 'Текст который будет записан в файл с именем file1.txt (level-3.js)';
const data2 = 'Текст который будет записан в файл с именем file12.txt (level-3.js)';
const data3 = 'Текст который будет записан в файл с именем file123.txt (level-3.js)';

const full = data1 + data2 + data3;

const numbers = full.match(/(?<=file)(\d+)(?=\.txt)/g);

console.log(numbers);

const result = full.replace(/(?<=file)(\d+)(?=\.txt)/g, '')

console.log(result);
```

Comment: То же склонялся к такому варианту. Вчера как раз начал читать про ретроспективные проверки.
Проблема в том что это вариант у меня не срабатывает если я делаю отрицание:
`/[^(?<=file)(\d+)(?=\.txt)]/`

Comment: @TupoScrip то есть, вы не правильно сформулировали задачу и надо удалить эти символы? Если да - обновил ответ, если нет - уточните что хотите сделать

Comment: Да вот теперь всё верно. Нужен был массив с числами. Тот что находится в переменной numbers в вашем коде. Ответ принял, спасибо.

PS совсем забыл про метод String.prototype.match и писал какую-то ерунду. Оказывается всё можно сделать в одну строку.

Comment: До апдейта он и был, массив этот, с числами. Будьте внимательней

Comment: Точно, это меня чёт переклинило :))